# Employer coverage for International travel

Tags: employer, travel, expenses

My company expects me to travel to Baja California Mexico 1-2 times per month to perform work, such work involves multiple destinations soon after crossing the international border approx. 4hrs of travel. In my original employee contract requests of these measures had yet to be discussed and to date have not been discussed. I am assuming they are waiting for me to bring up the request.
About 4 months ago i submitted a complaint to HR informing my manager and Human resource manager that not only was i uncomfotarble at times, that i began to have health issues. I then proceeded to explain the financial burden impacted by my absence for home responsabilities.Last month I sat down with my Human resouces and Direct Manager and told them I was not going to travel very often for work, unless I was compensated for my hardship, insured by the company when traveling and reimbursed for all expenses related to traveling for work. Today my Boss asked me to travel for work!

What right do I have working for this privatly owned LLC Business? How do I ask my employer to cover loss time with family, additional incurred expenses at home,international travel insurance and or a "per diem" while traveling for work?

Comment: I assume since you can get to that area of Mexico in 4 hours that you are probably coming from the United States.  It isn't clear whether this is a new job that involves travel or a job you've had for a long time that is suddenly involving travel.  What was the nature of the HR complaint?  Is that somehow related to travel?  Or is that a separate issue?  What expenses are not being reimbursed?

Comment: You have the right to refuse to go. They have the right to fire you for cause if you insist on not performing reasonable assigned duties. Rights don't help you here.

Comment: Ive been with the company for 10 years, the complaint was about the health risks, travel funds, risk insurance and additional cost out of pocket to hire child care. All travel purchases are being reimbursed with reciept proof.

Comment: Travel funds: Have you asked about a travel advance, and/or a company credi card for the purpise?

Comment: Child care, I'm afraid, is generally your responsibility. As is personal travel insurance, usually, though some companies do offer related services. (Mine doesn't insure me against plane crashes -- except via the standard employee life policy -- but does provide out-of-country health emergency services including an "international 911" service  and medevac if needed.)

Comment: Health risks: Medically-directed travel innoculations are often reimbursable.

Comment: Sounds logical, Best to just ask for a meeting and ask for the neccessary and desired support for the work to be done.

Comment: @keshlam Interesting. In Europe we wouldn't be allowed to board the flight if there were problems with the company's insurance. @ OP: given your updates, do you still have a practical question that needs answering? In case you've looked at the related questions (on the sidebar on the right) and still have an unsolved problem, please modify your question to focus it on a single core question with practical answers.

Comment: *I submitted a complaint to HR informing my manager and Human resource manager that [I] was uncomfortable...* - What was the outcome of this discussion?

Comment: It sounds like you are working with HR rather than your boss to sort out the issues around travel, which seems odd.

Comment: NO company I ever heard of would reimburse you for child care when you travel, that is just ridiculous. It isn't the company's fault that you chose to have children. If you don't want to travel, then get another job, clearly this one requires travel.  An expectation to be reimbursed for travel expenses such as airfare, rental car, mileage if using your own car, meal expenses. Those are reasonable and ordinary in the travel world.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I ask my employer to cover loss time with family, additional incurred expenses at home,international travel insurance and or a "per diem" while traveling for work?

Keep receipts, this is a must when travelling for work. Bring those with you when talking to HR. They will show expenses incurred.

For the rest, you haven't listed what expenses are incurred by you not being home. If this is about moonlighting outside work, then it's probably not a great idea to bring it up. If it's expenses such as babysitters or other unavoidable issues. Then list them and you may get lucky with HR.

Lost time with family is part of the job you contracted to do, unsure how you could put a $$ figure on that, and it seems very unlikely anyone would take it seriously.

For a per diem, that realistically should have been negotiated earlier, but it's not too late to do so. With all the rest though it might be a bit much.

Health problems? This could be anything, so I won't go in to it too much, if it's just that Mexican food doesn't agree with you then it's too minor to complain about. 4 hours travel doesn't seem a huge deal to me and it probably won't to HR either.

So in summary, get all your paperwork together before you talk to HR and negotiate from the strongest position you can. Personally I would tone it down, take out some of the more unreasonable issues which make it sound like a rant and negotiate on the more normal ones. Travel expenses, unavoidable expenses and suchlike.

Keep it professional.

Comment: Yep. Ask what's available rather than making demands, and you may find that a lot if it is already covered. At least some of the rest, I'm afraid, is in the category of "Maybe you would be happier working elsewhere, since that's your issue rather than the company's."

Comment: I agree with the relocation option, however I like where I work, it seems that I need to just get all my requests in order and meet with the President and Human Resouces discuss the opportunities and determine the next actions.....Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Good luck, and I mean that sincerely... but ask befors you demand, and consider that demanding may be a career-limiting action. And talk to HR before you try talking to the president, or you're likely to be thrown out of the office with "Why are you bothering me with this? That's HR and//or Travel and/or Purchasing"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken most companies provide a company credit card to their employees for travel. Some companies reimburse you later once you show them a saved receipt and fall within the budge/rules. For example, last company I was at allowed me a budget for gas, food, and hotel but I had to pay it all out of pocket. Once I got back, we scanned the receipts and submitted to HR/Payroll. Next pay period I get my pay plus the travel expense.

So basically I would see if the company has a company card and ask for one. Use it strictly for travel on company's time for gas, food, and hotel.

Child care usually falls on you but if your company expects you to pay your entire travel expense without help then I would consider leaving because that would cost a lot of money over time.